# python function not returning populated array

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm working with an online class and can't seem to diagnose this bug. In the code below, if the player initially responds no to the prompt in draw_one_more() the correct value is returned. If the player takes one or more cards and eventually indicates no prior to busting, the value None is returned. I added a print statement directly before the return, and print statement shows the correctly populated value, but the value received from the function is None.

**UPDATES**
I got a bit carried away after working with some recursive examples. As many suggested the problem doesn't require recursion, and TBF is probably a bad use case. I added some more code as requested.

```
def draw_card(hand, card_deck, todraw=1):
    for i in range(todraw):
        hand.append(card_deck[random.choice(card_deck)])
    return hand

player_hand = draw_card(hand=player_hand,
                        card_deck = card_deck,
                        todraw=2)

#3D - establish player draw loop
def draw_one_more(ahand):
    #print(player_hand)
    print(f"line 125 {ahand}")
    draw_another = input("Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass: ")
    print("Line 128 Draw another: " + draw_another)
    if draw_another != 'y':
        print(f"line 129 inside NO returning {ahand}")
        return ahand
    else:
        ahand = draw_card(hand=ahand,
                            card_deck = card_deck,
                            todraw=1)
        ascore = add_cards(ahand)
        #exit 2 - bust
        if ascore > 21:
            print(f"\tYour cards: {ahand}, current score: {ascore}: PLAYER BUSTS")
            print(f"\tComputer's first card: {computer_hand[0]}")
            return ahand
        #continue recursively
        print(f"\tYour cards: {ahand}, current score: {ascore}")
        print(f"\tComputer's first card: {computer_hand[0]}")
        draw_one_more(ahand)

#4 - computer run loop 
#first run player execution
player_hand = draw_one_more(player_hand)
print(f"line 148 player hand {player_hand}")
player_score = add_cards(player_hand)
```

Comment: Your else block has no return statement unless `ascore > 21`

Comment: You generally need to return the result of recursive calls. `return draw_one_more(ahand)`

Comment: Do you _need_ recursion? What is that trying to solve over a standard loop?

Comment: Where is the ``player_hand`` function? please share it.

Comment: This is not a problem for recursion.  This is a problem for looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if in the first call to draw_one_more() draw_another == 'y', your function will always return None.

in recursive functions the value returned is always the first return, if your function does not return then you will get None.

EX:

first call to draw_one_more():

. draw_another == 'y'

then your function will execute the else statement and return None as you have no return statement inside the else.

EX:

```
def foo(x):
    if (x < 10)
        return x
    else
        foo(x - 1)
```

is the same as

```
def foo(x):
    if (x < 10)
        return x
    else
        foo(x - 1)
        return None
```

when you call foo(x), if x < 10 your function will return x, otherwise, None

Comment: thank you. So would I update at the very bottom to include draw_one_more(ahand) and then return ahand?